# Mal'cev completion of nilpotent groups

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, algebraic-groups

Is the $\mathbb{R}$-Mal'cev completion of a finitely generated torsion free nilpotent group connected and simply connected?.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.